# Where do the universe embedds to in Reinhardt's cardinals setting?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals

I just want to understand the embedding behind Reinhardt's cardinals. We have an elementary embedding $j: V \to V$. Let the background theory be $\sf MK - Choice$. We know that $V$ itself is a class stage of the cumulative hierarchy, i.e. there is a class ordinal $\kappa$ such that $V=V_\kappa$, but this means that the range of $j$, being structure preserving, would also be a stage of the cumulative hierarchy, this would be $V_{j(\kappa)}$. So, either $j(\kappa)= \kappa$, by then $j$ would be an automorphism, but $V$ is a well-founded transitive class model of $\sf ZF$, and I think it can't admit automorphisms over it. So $j(\kappa) \neq \kappa$, but this leads to $j(\kappa) < \kappa$, and so $V_{j(\kappa)} \in V$, but this would be inconsistent since $j$ is freely used in Replacement and Separation.

> Where is the flaw in the above argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An elementary embedding is not an automorphism, although an automorphism *would be* an elementary embedding. But an elementary embedding is not requiring to be surjective.

An elementary embedding just means that the images satisfy the same properties of their origin, in the codomain space that is. In the case of an elementary embedding $V\to V$ it just means that $x$ and $j(x)$ have the same first order properties. And indeed, if $\kappa<j(\kappa)$, then there is no reason to expect that some $\alpha$ is mapped to $\kappa$ at all. We do not expect that in the case of measurable cardinal, or even weaker theories, like the transfer principle from the reals to the hyperreals.

However, much like any other function that the universe is closed under, it will have fixed points. Many of them. So having $j(x)=x$ also tells you very little about the general behaviour of $j$. So, again, it is not enough to deduce that it is surjective just because we found some $\lambda$ such that $j(\lambda)=\lambda$.

Your main problem is overusing $\kappa$. $V$ is just $V$, if you *really must insist* on thinking of it as a stage in the von Neumann hierarchy, then it is $V_{\rm Ord}$. The elementary embedding is defined on sets, so $j(\mathrm{Ord})$ is not a set, and while we can define $j$ on class as $j(X)=\bigcup_{\alpha\in\rm Ord}j(X\cap V_\alpha)$, there is no reason to expect $j$ to behave exactly as it does with sets.

Comment: if an elementary embedding is also surjective wouldn't that make it an automorphism?

Comment: Yes, but why would it be surjective, unless it is trivial?

Comment: Good! Try to go one level above MK, that is let us work with ZF + some strong inaccessible exists. Now take $V_\kappa$ where $\kappa$ is the first strong inaccessible. Let $j: V_\kappa \to V_\kappa$, and such that $j$ is an elementary embedding that is non-trivial; now take the function $j^+ : V_{\kappa +1} \to V_{\kappa+1}; j^+(x)= j [x]=\{j(y) \mid y \in x\}$, this would also be elementary embedding. Now, what is $j^+(\kappa)$ ? If it equals $\kappa$, then $j$ would be an automorphism which can't be, so $j^+(\kappa) < \kappa$ but this embeds $V_\kappa$  to an element of it?

Comment: Why would it be an elementary embedding? $j^+(\kappa)=j[\kappa]$ is not an ordinal if $j$ is non-trivial. This may preserve some modicum of elementarity with regards to the second-order theory of $V_\kappa$, but it is no longer a fully elementary embedding. There is a whole theory on when and how these embeddings can be lifted and by how much. It is complicated, it is difficult, and it is full of subtlety which you are currently sweeping off the table. I am not an expert on those things either, but Gabe and Farmer both have papers on this and both are around often.

Comment: $j^+(x)=j(x)$ for all $x \in V_\kappa$, so all ordinals in $\kappa$ will be sent by $j^+$ to ordinals in $\kappa$, now $j^+$ would preserve transitivity, and so $j^+(\kappa)$ would be a transitive set of transitive sets, and this is an ordinal in a well founded milieu.

Comment: You are assuming that $\kappa$ was the critical point of the embedding? In that case $j\colon V_\kappa\to V_\kappa$ was the identity. Again, your mistakes stem from an overloading and overusing the letter $\kappa$.

Comment: No! I didn't make that assumption.

Comment: Either the critical point of $j$ is below $\kappa$, in which case $j[\kappa]\neq\kappa$, or it is trivial. Those are the only two options. Choose one of them, then go back to my previous comments.

Comment: Of course the first. Still $j^+(\kappa)$ is a transitive set of transitive sets, and so an ordinal. I'm still not seeing how $j^+(\kappa)$ fails to be an ordinal?

Comment: No. If $j$ is non-trivial, there is some $\alpha<\kappa$ such that $j(\alpha)>\alpha$. Then the first such $\alpha$ will not be in $j[\kappa]$. Full stop.

Comment: Why not $j(\alpha) <\alpha$?

Comment: Because then $j^{n+1}(\alpha)<j^n(\alpha)$ and you got yourself a decreasing sequence of ordinals. Normally, something that is frowned upon in the context of ZF and related theories. Note that if $j$ is at all amenable to the universe, then this gives you a fairly simple definition as far as Separation goes.

Comment: I always thought that for any elementary embedding $j$ we have $j(x)=j[x]$ for all $x$, since elementary embeddings must preserve membership $\in$. Now, let $\lambda$ be above the critical point of $j$, and $\lambda < \kappa$, we have $V_\kappa \models ordinal (\lambda)$, now if $j(\lambda)= j[\lambda]$, then by your argument $ V_\kappa \models \neg ordinal(j(\lambda))$, violating $j$ be an elementary embedding?

Comment: Since anything above the critical point will **not** satisfy $j(\lambda) = j[\lambda]$, I don't see why this is an issue. In fact you don't necessarily have $\sup j[\lambda] = j(\lambda)$...

Comment: but $j$, being an elementary embedding, is supposed to preserve $\in$, that is $x \in y \iff j(x) \in j(y)$, this entails that for ANY set $s$ we have $j(s)=j[s]$

Comment: Why does that entail that?

Comment: Ah! I see, $j$ is not surjective! So, there can exist  $\alpha \in j(\lambda)$ where $\alpha$ is outside the range of $j $